# How do you reference a RelativeLayout in order to add a TextView?

Tags: android

I am attempting to reference an xml file in order to add a TextView dynamically in Android studio. I've tried to create a RelativeLayout object and add the TextView to that. I've tried to give the RelativeView xml block an id and reference that. Both times nothing shows up. Any guesses on what I'm doing wrong?

Here is my code:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    RelativeLayout rl = new RelativeLayout(this);

    firstNumber = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.numberOne);
    firstNumber.setText(String.valueOf(myAddition.getNumOne()));
    secondNumber = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.numberTwo);
    secondNumber.setText(String.valueOf(myAddition.getNumTwo()));

    brandNew = new TextView(this);
    brandNew.setText("Hello");
    rl.addView(brandNew);

}
```

Here's the xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"     
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"     
    tools:context=".MainActivityFragment">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Math Champ"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="87"
    android:id="@+id/numberOne"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="99dp" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="21"
    android:id="@+id/numberTwo"
    android:layout_below="@+id/numberOne"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="@string/default_answer"
    android:id="@+id/answer"
    android:layout_below="@+id/numberTwo"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<Button xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/button_send"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/button_send"
    android:onClick="sendMessage"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/answer"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: the issue here is that you are creating a new RelativeLayout, but never adding it to the hierarchy. `setContentView(rl)` would show that layout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't create a new RelativeLayout.  Use something like this instead to get a reference to the RelativeLayout already created in the XML:

```
RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout )findViewById(R.id.relativeLayoutId);
```

Note,

```
R.id.relativeLayoutId
```

would be whatever you specify as the id in the XML.  So for example:

```
<RelativeLayout
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:id="@+id/relativeLayoutId">
```